# I just can use one operator, i need more operator

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, math, handlebars.js

My handlebars code

```
 {{#each data}}
          <tr>
            <td align="left"><font size="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; {{nama_produk}}</font></td>
            <td align="left"><font size="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{jumlah_beli}}</font></td>
            <td align="left"><font size="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Rp. {{harga_satuan}}</font></td>
            <td align="left"><font size="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; {{diskon}}</font></td>
            <td align="left"><font size="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Rp. {{math jumlah_beli "*" harga_satuan "-" jumlah_beli "*" harga_satuan "/" diskon}} </font></td>
          </tr>
          {{else}}
            <h1>Unknown Data</h1>
          {{/each}}
```

My helper code

```
hbs.registerHelper("math", function(lvalue, operator, rvalue, op

tions) {
  lvalue = parseFloat(lvalue);
  rvalue = parseFloat(rvalue);

  return {
      "+": lvalue + rvalue,
      "-": lvalue - rvalue,
      "*": lvalue * rvalue,
      "/": lvalue / rvalue,
      "%": lvalue % rvalue
  }[operator];
});
```

if i write like this, result appear

```
<td align="left"><font size="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Rp. {{math jumlah_beli "*" harga_satuan}} </font></td>
```

but my problem is, if i write like this, not result appear.

```
<td align="left"><font size="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Rp. {{math jumlah_beli "*" harga_satuan "-" jumlah_beli "*" harga_satuan "/" diskon}} </font></td>
```